# What does "advanced simple template" mean in the context of a creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-templates

In the horse's bestiary entry it states that a heavy horse gains the "advanced simple template" and I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: What terrible phrasing...

Answer (score 20):

**It's a specific template**

[This](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1) is the Advanced simple template. Simple Templates are like normal templates, but they barely change anything; they're intended to quickly and easily improve, or nerf, a creature in a way you can do with a minimum of effort. The "Advanced" simple template is a specific simple template.